# Efficient query from multiple tables with multiple results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have searched and can't find exactly what I am looking for so thought I would ask this question.

Right now my page takes a while to load because of the Multiple Queries.

So, for example, the Top Table is Classrooms

Which will then Grab Locations, This Will have multiple locations, not just one.

Then, of course, there will be teachers but multiple teachers.

The way I have structured it I first get a list of the Classrooms then in that loop I get all the Locations, Then I get all the Teachers.

What would be the most efficient way to do this so it does not take the page forever to load.

And right now I have loaded all results for the year. I will add a filter by location and teacher.

Comment: This is not a question. We have no idea what your data looks like, or how your code is structured. There isn't much we can offer for help. I would suggest, though, do not loop one recordset and retrieve a second in each iteration. Instead retrieve it all at once using JOINs.

Comment: how would I go about that if for example I have 1 class with 5 locations. which the locations are in another table.

Comment: `SELECT classroom.*, location.* FROM classroom INNER JOIN locations ON classroom.location_id = location.id where classroom.id = 1` Now you have a record set with 3 records for classroom number "1" each with different location information. One trip to the database, 3 records.